# how to use svg file in bottom nav bar in flutter?

Tags: flutter

1. Is it right the way to put external icon in bottomnavigationbar is only by svg file?
2. if understand like question 1 through googling, so I tried like below code but it appers just label from text, no apper icon. How can I resolve it?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0.0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        leading: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_outlined),
         title: Text ('MY ID Balance \$298.98'),
        actions: [Icon(Icons.menu)],
      ),
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                image: AssetImage('assets/image/auth_background.png')
            )
        ),

      ),
      bottomNavigationBar:
    BottomNavigationBar(
    type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
    items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
    icon: SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/bottomnav/menu.svg', width: 25, color: Colors.black,),
    label: 'menu'
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
    icon: SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/bottomnav/pfp.svg', color: Colors.black54, width: 30),
    label: 'pfp',
    ),
   
    
    ],
    )

    );
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you set assets/icons/bottomnav/ path in pubspec.yaml file ?

Comment: I did there assets/icons. (except of bottomnav beacause is below in icons) Is it not okay? @Vishal Zaveri

Answer (score 1):

Not all SVGs are supported by this package.

Your SVG is probably not supported. Verify by running this snippet,

```
final SvgParser parser = SvgParser();
try {
  parser.parse('assets/icons/bottomnav/menu.svg', warningsAsErrors: true);
  print('SVG is supported');
} catch (e) {
  print('SVG contains unsupported features');
}
```

Comment: Where I have to write your code? @rrttrr

Comment: Try inside initState for now. If you get some error logs, that means that SVG is unsupported.